# Express response URLs

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, redirect, webserver

I am building a web app in NodeJS and Express. I have an express webserver and an EJS client. for many of my server requests, I need one url, but when I use `res.render("home.ejs",{user:users[i]})`, I am not able to change the url of the rendered view, meaning when I check login info from `/login`, my homepage will render on `/login` instead of `/home`. to change the url, I would need to use `res.redirect()`, but this does not work with res.render or my EJS views. can somebody please help me change the url while still choosing my desired view.

this is the code that I would like to fix

````
app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
for(var i=0;i<users.length+1;i++){
    if(i<users.length){
    if(users[i].name==req.body.username&&users[i].password==req.body.password){
         //console.log(req.body)
         console.log("attempting to log in!")
      // res.render("index.ejs",{data:req.body})
      console.log(users[i])
      console.log("logged in")
      res.render("home.ejs",{user:users[i]})
      break;
      //means that account has been found
      }else if(users[i].name==req.body.username&&users[i].password!=req.body.password){
        res.render("errorlogin.ejs",{error:"incorrect password"})
        //only one of each name, so account has been found
        break;
      }else if(users[i].name!=req.body.username&&users[i].password!=req.body.password){
          //if neither pw or name match, it means we need to keep searching
          
          continue
    }else if(!req.body.password||req.body.password==null){
//if there's no pw... you get it...
        res.render("errorlogin.ejs",{error:"incorrect password"})
        break;
    }
    //no need to check for pw, bc it's not unique, the combo, or the name is.
}else{
        res.render("errorlogin.ejs",{error:"account does not exist. please register below."})
}
}
})```
````

Comment: Please show us your code.  It sounds like you aren't understanding some fundamental principles of how web servers and clients work, but to help you more specifically, we need to see the relevant code.

Comment: Indeed if you post a form from `/login` and want to go to a different URL after that, then you should `res.redirect()` to that new URL after a successful login.  I'm not sure what the problem is with that.  Your EJS template will render for the NEW url that you redirect to.  Any login state you want to store should be saved in a server-side session and you can access that when you render the page for a new URL.

Comment: I understand, but I need to render specific information onto that page, like the user that logged in so I can add user specific information. this would mean I would need to use both `res.redirect()` and `res.render("/...",{user:...,})`, which is not possible

Comment: Do you understand what a server-side session is?  That's where you store what user it is.  So, after you do `res.redirect()`, when the browser follows the redirect and comes back to the server for the redirected page, you can then render that page with information from the session that was put in the session when the user logged in.  This is how the flow works in these circumstances.

Comment: Ok! I found a good resource on express server sessions! I learned more and this and it is exactly what I need! thank you for pointing me in the right direction and I'll keep you and the rest of this thread posted!